# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.layers.pooling'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Im writing this code in google colaboratory

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.pooling import AveragePooling2D
```

and it  gives error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.layers.pooling'
```

I copied code from : https://www.kaggle.com/nandinibagga/real-life-violence-detection-using-inceptionv3#Real-Life-Violence-Detection-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is old, the pooling module has been changed to maxpooling.

You can look at the link for more info: [Keras Layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers)